# Can VoipHttpIncomingCallTask bring WP8 app to foreground?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-voip

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight App based on the ChatterBox sample.
I can send a raw push notification to my app and a scheduled background task will start.

When the sample receives that push it will communicate with the Backend and simulate an incoming call.

In my case, I need to send a SIP REGISTER so that a SIP INVITE can arrive to the App and that will trigger all the VoipCoordinator mechanism.

The most practical way to do this is to bring my app to foreground, which will then send a SIP REGISTER.

Any hint?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you can push a Toast and when that Toast is pressed, it will activate the app.